# Crusty eyes in the morning

Tags: human-biology, physiology, eyes

Often, after waking up from a night's sleep hard, flaky, pale yellow crystals are deposited around the eyelids (which easily wash off with water).

What are these? Why are they yellow? What are they made of? Is their amount proportional to the length of sleep?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is quite common. It is most likely dried **rheum** (also know by slang terms such as "sleep", "eye boogers", "eye crusties", etc.).

**Rheum** is the result of dried **mucus**, **tears** (and the **salt** and **minerals** therein), as well as dead **blood** and **skin cells**.

Essentially it is all the stuff that’s normally in your eye that eventually dries up making the contents more condensed giving it a light yellow color. When all that stuff is in your tears it is spread out enough that your tears are still mostly clear.